# How do I display more JSON items in HTML using WebKit?

Tags: html, json, swift, swifty-json

I am building a news app using SwiftyJSON and I have been able to pull the data properly. I am also able to display the title and description in a tableView. However, when I go to the Detail View I want to be able to display the full article summary from the feed.

Here are the feed elements:

```
func parse(json: JSON) {
        for article in json["articles"].arrayValue {
            let title = article["title"].stringValue
            let author = article["author"].stringValue
            let date = article["publishedAt"].stringValue
            let image = article["urlToImage"].stringValue
            let description = article["description"].stringValue

            let obj = ["title": title, "author": author, "date": date, "image": image, "description": description, ]
            news.append(obj)

        }
```

I am sending the data to the Detail View Controller as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailViewController()
        vc.articleSummary = news[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Then on the Detail View Controller here is the code. The commented items are items that I would like to add to the display:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var articleSummary: [String: String]!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard articleSummary != nil else { return }

        if let description = articleSummary["description"] {
            var html = "<html>"
            html += "<head>"
            html += "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
            html += "<style> body { font-size: 150%; } </style>"
            html += "</head>"
            html += "<body>"
         // html += <h1>title</h1>
         // html += <h4>author</h4>
         // html += <p>date</p>
         // html += <img src="image" alt="" />
            html += description
            html += "</body>"
            html += "</html>"
            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how did you add your webView on your ViewController?

Comment: what is the problem with your code? is it throwing an error when you uncomment those lines?

Comment: If I uncomment the code it show as the word not the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the HTML string properly and your data will be displayed.

```
if let description = articleSummary["description"],
   let title = articleSummary["title"],
   let author = articleSummary["author"],
   let image = articleSummary["image"],
   let date = articleSummary["date"] {
        var html = "<html>"
        html += "<head>"
        html += "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
        html += "<style> body { font-size: 150%; } </style>"
        html += "</head>"
        html += "<body>"
        html += "<h1>\(title)</h1>"
        html += "<h4>\(author)</h4>"
        html += "<p>\(date)</p>"
        html += "<img src=\"\(image)\" alt=\"\" />"
        html += description
        html += "</body>"
        html += "</html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I get errors for each item saying “Use of unresolved identifier ...”

Comment: you need to add those variables in the if let statement. check my updated answer

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.